# How to add complete new page at the end of existing crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

How do i add complete new page at the end of existing crystal report?
I don't want to repeat any header or footer on this new page from existing report.
I found couple of posts related to this. I tried what they explained but still didn't work.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: A blank page? Or a page with a static content?

Comment: Could you elaborate upon what you have already tried that didn't work?  A link to the source would be useful, along with a description of the output it produced and how that output differs from your desired output.